# date comparison in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am comparing date with some static values and some variables here is my code

```
IF v_next_date >= STR_TO_DATE('15/2/2014', '%m/%d/%Y') then 
      SET v_next_date = DATE_FORMAT(v_date,'%2000-%m-%d');
elseif v_next_date = v_date then
 LEAVE last_update;
else
  SET v_next_date = DATE_ADD(v_next_date,INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
end if;
```

in first if I want to compare static date and then assign the v_date to v_next_date so the year should be 2000.
in second I want to compare 2 variables 
in third if I want to assign the next month same date to v_next_date.

EDIT: my procedure don't complete, I think there is problem in comparison or assignment

EDIT: here is my full code ( procedure ):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE accidents.`task_7_proce`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE v_pkid INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_mine INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_date DATETIME;
  DECLARE v_lat INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_lng INTEGER;
  DECLARE v_next_date DATE;
  DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE msg varchar(100) DEFAULT 'no message';

DECLARE weather_cursor CURSOR FOR select pkid, mine_id, accident_dt, lat, lng
                              from test_unfilteredfull
                              where pkid = 46953;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN weather_cursor;


    FETCH weather_cursor INTO v_pkid, v_mine, v_date, v_lat, v_lng;

    SET v_next_date = DATE_ADD(v_date,INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

last_update: loop  


    -- ******** update statement **************
      UPDATE mytable mt INNER JOIN myvalues mv
      ON mv.date = v_next_date and
      mt.pkid = v_pkid 
      SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax, mt.tmin = mv.tmin, mt.dayl= mv.dayl ,
      mt.prcp = mv.prcp , mt.srad = mv.srad, mt.swe=mv.swe, mt.vp=mv.vp
      WHERE mv.Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
      mv.Longitude_MIN <= v_lng and 
      mv.Latitude_MAX >=  v_lat and  
      mv.Latitude_MIN <= v_lat;

if ROW_COUNT() > 0 then
   SET msg = 'Successfully updated!';
   LEAVE last_update;
end if;

IF v_next_date >= STR_TO_DATE('2/15/2014', '%m/%d/%Y') then 
  SET v_next_date = DATE_FORMAT(v_date,'%2000-%m-%d');
elseif v_next_date = v_date then
  LEAVE last_update;
else
  SET v_next_date = DATE_ADD(v_next_date,INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

end if;

END LOOP last_update;
CLOSE weather_cursor;
commit;  

END;
```

Comment: More details,whats the issue?

Comment: my procedure don't complete. I think there is some issue with comparison and assignment, can you review the code.

Comment: `'%2000-%m-%d'` isn't a valid date format.  You might mean:  `''%Y-%m-%d'`.

Comment: how can I assign the static year '2000' and month and day from variable v_date?

Comment: @GordonLinoff select DATE_FORMAT('2014-3-4','%2000-%m-%d'); this return '2000-3-4'. why the above format is invalid?

Comment: Share the rest of your code i.e., the earlier statements where v_next_date is assigned. Also don't you want your first STR_TO_DATE to use the format string: `%d/%m/%Y`

Comment: @AgRizzo full code is now in my question.

Comment: @Muhammad . . . `'%2000'` is an invalid format.  It happens to work, but a clearer way to write what you are doing is:  `DATE_FORMAT(date('2014-03-04'), '2000-%m-%d')`.  Note the use of the ISO-standard date format, the explicit use of `date()` to make the conversion, and the absence of `%` before `2000`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1 more problem, I want to loop through multiple pkid, in that case if an update is successful my code kick me out from the loop and close the cursor, how can I proceed to the next pkid from the cursor?